# Redirecting between zones in MOSS 2007

Tags: security, web-application-zones

I have Two zones(Intranet and Internet) for a MOSS Team site.I want something like this

When a Intranet(Local AD User) user try to visit Internet zone, he/she should be redirected to the Intranet Zone.

If a User Outside AD visits Intranet zone,he/she should be redirceted to Internet zone.

Appreciate if you have a solution to this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You dont actually says if you want AD users to be able to login remotely, so ill assume not (because its kind of a security risk if you dont set it up right)

You should probably have a split DNS, so that your public DNS only has the internet url and the internal DNS only has the internal url. This way external users will never see the intranet url, and vica versa.

But if you still want to proceed, you could build a HttpModule to redirect traffic, usually based on IP (as long as the internal network has its own ip), or if you just want it on the login page, add a control/webpart.

Comment: Actual scenario is I have Two ADs.MOSS is integrated with one AD only.So I want my other AD users(who don't have access to sharepoint) to access Internet zone which is anynomous site.

I have created a HTTP Module to redirect. But MOSS gives login prompt before HTTP module executes.It asks for Login prompt for the AD users for who are not in sharepoint infrastructure.

Comment: what event did you subscribe to in the HttpModule? BeginRequest?

Comment: I have tried with BeginRequest, End Request, PostAuthenticateRequest.Am i missing something ?

Comment: Do you end the request after you do the redirect? Otherwise the page will try to authenticate.

Comment: I was trying to debug.It's not hitting on Init() function.

Comment: It does come to Init() function, when i login with a user or the site is automatically login.

Comment: It seems Login prompt comes before HttpModule. Is there any other Solution ?